# How to map the path of the spring form select to byte variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the list like given below

```
<form:select class="inputField" path="var1">
                                        <form:options items="${list}" />
                                        </form:select>
```

However , I am putting the arraylist of string type from my controller , it gives me NumberFormatException when displaying the page , var1 is of type Byte , if I change the var1 to other variable of integer type this works well , and it shows the values in dropdown.

But I want to map it to var1 which is of type byte.

Comment: How is your `${list}` populated in the controller? Does it only contain values that can be cast to a `Byte`?

Comment: ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String(); and string list here is not empty when I pass through controller

Comment: @mthmulders:My list contains the String values but I want to map to Byte varaible when user submits the form.

Comment: Are *all* of the values in that list valid `Byte` values? I.e., no non-numerical values, no values below `-128`, no values above `127`?

Comment: @mthmulders: look list contains the string values , but I should match the index of the list to the byte variable which is there in my model

Comment: Can you give a part of the stacktrace, maybe?